# Alternative source for Pathfinder (or Starfinder) Society School items

Tags: pathfinder-2e, starfinder, pathfinder-society

If you play in Pathfinder Society, you can pick a School (Spells, Scrolls, etc). These give you a free item for each Society game, and a skill feat on level 5 among other things.

Up until a few day ago<sup>*</sup>, I just went on to [www.organizedplayfoundation.org](https://organizedplayfoundation.org/Lorespire/pfs2guide._.Additional-Character-Options#contentSchools-1) to check the options. However, now I am greeted by an error message:

> This Account has been suspended

Where *else* can I find the rules?

---

*) It was definitely offline on October 23, and according to the Wayback Machine, it was still online on October 16. So sometime between the two.

Comment: If someone remembers the exact date the site went offline, please let me know and I will update the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [The Society guides are available online again](https://lorespire.paizo.com/)

Even the design is updated somewhat. The Pathfinder [items are here](https://lorespire.paizo.com/tiki-index.php?page=pfs2guide._.Additional-Character-Options#Pathfinder_Training).

Answer (score 5):

PDFs can be reached from the Paizo site:

- [Pathfinder Society](https://downloads.paizo.com/OP-Sanctioning/PFS2+Guide+v+4.04.pdf)
- [Starfinder Society](https://downloads.paizo.com/OP-Sanctioning/SFS+Guide+v+5.04.pdf)